# Percorrer inputs com jquery e verificar se tem determinada classe no input

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html5

Estou pegando os inputs com o código `var itensTabelaPresentation = ('#tabelaPresentarion > li');` e gostaria de percorrer eles e ir verificando se eles tem determinada classe, como realizo isso em um foreach?

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabelaPresentarion">
 <li role="presentation" id="tabGeral" class="active"><a href="#">Geral</a></li>
 <li role="presentation" id="tabAuditoria" ><a href="#">Audiroria</a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  var tabGeral = $('#tabGeral');
  var tabAuditoria = $('#tabAuditoria');

  var painelGeral = $('#painelGeral');
  var painelAuditoria = $('#painelAuditoria');

  var itensTabelaPresentation = ('#tabelaPresentarion > li');
  
  tabGeral.click(function () {
   painelGeral.show();
   painelAuditoria.hide();

   for (var i = 0; i <= itensTabelaPresentation.length; i++) {
    
   }

  });

  tabAuditoria.click(function () {
   painelGeral.hide();
   painelAuditoria.show();
  });
  
 });
</script>
```

Comment: De que input está falando?

Comment: Estou pegando a lista na verdade, ul > li .. vou editar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer assim com JQuery:

```
$('.nav.nav-tabs li').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('class') == "active"){
        alert("Achei a class!");
    } else {
        alert("A class não está aqui!");
    }
});
```

OBS: No lugar de `active` pela class que quer achar.

Comment: Perfeitamente amigo, era isso mesmo que precisava.

Comment: Se houver mais de uma classe no elemento, não irá funcionar.

Comment: Mas não vai ter, porque ele que só a class active. Um elemento só vai ter. Mas se for ter mesmo, não vai dar certo.

Comment: só trocar o `attr('class') == "active"` por `hasClass('active')` que fica tudo certo

Answer (score 4):

Basta você utilizar o [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) para isso.

```js
$("#tabelaPresentarion > li").each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
    console.log("O elemento " + index + ": " + $(this).text() + " está ativo.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabelaPresentarion">
  <li role="presentation" id="tabGeral" class="active"><a href="#">Geral</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" id="tabAuditoria"><a href="#">Audiroria</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Como você já tem a lista de elementos que vai usar para filtrar a classe, `var itensTabelaPresentation = ('#tabelaPresentarion > li');`, basta utilizar o método filter:

```
var soOsComClasse = itensTabelaPresentation.filter('.suaClasse');
```

Se precisa atravessar todos os itens mesmo, só usar o que você falou, `each()`, além do método `hasClass()`

```
itensTabelaPresentation.each(function(index) {
  console.log('elemento ' + index + ' tem classe? ' + $(this).hasClass('suaClasse'));
});
```

Mais informações:

- https://api.jquery.com/filter/
- https://api.jquery.com/each/
- https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/